# PyQt How to pass an index on click in QTreeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a dictionary with data in the form of a tree:

```
tree = {'parent 1': {'child 1 - 1': {'child 1 - 1 - 1': {'child 4 levl parent 1': {}}}, 'child 1 - 2': {'children 2- 1': {}}, 'child 1- 3': {}}, 'parent 2': {'parent 2- 1 - chil': {}}, 'parent 3': {}, 'parent 4': {}}
```

Next, I build a list for this dictionary:

```
def treeRubrics(self):
    self.treeList = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    self.treeList.setObjectName("treeList")
    self.treeList.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 0))
    self.treeList.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16777215))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeList, 3, 0, 1, 1)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.populateTree(self.tree, model.invisibleRootItem())
    self.treeList.setModel(model)
    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Records tree')
    self.treeList.expandAll()
    self.treeList.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)
    __sortingEnabled = self.treeList.isSortingEnabled()
    self.treeList.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

I process a mouse click on an item from the list:

```
def onSelectionChanged(self, *args):
    for sel in self.treeList.selectedIndexes():
        val = "/"+sel.data()
        while sel.parent().isValid():
            sel = sel.parent()
            val = "/" + sel.data()+ val
```

But this is how I get only a list of the selected names, for example:
`/parent 1/child 1 - 1/child 1 - 1 - 1/child 4 levl parent 1`

How can I change the dict "tree" and the code so that each element of the tree has its own index and when I click I pass the index of this record (Get this index in method onSelectionChanged)?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I think it is still pretty unclear what you problem is. 

You are creating a `QtGui.QStandardItemModel`. So every item of your model already has a index assigned to it. In addition to this you are already iteration over the selected indexes. Every aspect of your question seems to be already answered to me.